# Issues With FileSize Function

Tags: delphi

I am trying to use the system.filesize function to get the size of a file in delphi, it works ok for files < 4GB but fails for files > 4GB. 
so i implemented my own that opens the required file as a filestream and gets the streamsize which works perfectly.

Here is a Snippet

```
   function GiveMeSize(PathtoFile : string): int64;
   var
     stream : TFileStream;
     size : int64;
   begin
     try
       stream := TFileStream.Create(PathtoFile, fmOpenReadWrite or fmShareDenyNone);
       size := stream.size;     
     except
       showmessage('Unable to get FileSize');
     end
     finally    
       stream.free;
   end;
```

but the problem with my above function is that it opens the file which incurs some overhead when processing a large number of files.
is there any function that can get filesize of files > 4GB without opening the file first?
I have tried some functions online but they tend to report wrong file size for files greater than 4GB.

Delphi Version : XE5

Thanks.

Comment: No, the problem with the above function is that it won't even compile. Btw. your sharing mode is quite weird.

Comment: Sorry about that.
Just Whooped the code from my head in my browser. :)
But I do hope you understand what am trying to point out?

Comment: Please don't post fake code. Please take great care to post real code.

Comment: Am sorry, am currently away from my Development PC.
Noted. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`System.FileSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.FileSize) is a Pascal I/O function that operates on Pascal `File` variables. If you want to get the size of a file specified by path, then `System.FileSize` is simply wrong function to use.

What's more, you quite likely don't want to open the file just to obtain its size. I obtain the file size like this:

```
function FileSize(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  AttributeData: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
  if GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @AttributeData) then 
  begin
    Int64Rec(Result).Lo := AttributeData.nFileSizeLow;
    Int64Rec(Result).Hi := AttributeData.nFileSizeHigh;
  end 
  else 
    Result := -1;
end;
```

Comment: Choose this as "accepted answer" because it does not use "FindFirst" Stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Googling for the keywords "delphi get file size int64" gives you plenty of examples

I use this:

```
function GetSizeOfFile(const Filename: string): Int64;
var
 sr : TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(fileName, faAnyFile, sr ) <> 0 then
    Exit(-1);
  try
    result := Int64(sr.FindData.nFileSizeHigh) shl Int64(32) + Int64(sr.FindData.nFileSizeLow);
  finally
    System.SysUtils.FindClose(sr) ;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This code has its issues. For instance, ask yourself what happens when you pass it the path `'C:\Windows\System32\*.dll'`. That's always been one of my bugbears about the use of `FindFirstFile` for things other than enumerating files.

Comment: @David, I would keep responsibility to pass a *single file name* on a consumer of this code. But agree with you that `FindFirst` should be used for enumerating files, not for anything else.

Comment: @TLama It's true that this is a little far-fetched. The user can reasonably be expected not to pass wildcards to this function I suppose. But code like this has always bugged me when there are perfectly good alternatives. I suspect that way back when, `FindFirstFile` was the fastest API for reading attributes, but MS dealt with that in XP by adding `GetFileAttributesEx`.

Comment: @David, In JCL `FindFirstFile` is also used to obtain file size (at least in my current JCL version). I Never used `GetFileAttributesEx` (XP+) so +1 for both of you. learning all the time :)

Comment: I have copied the code from a context where it's save to assume that a single valid filename ist passed. But of course you guys are right, I just thought I'd share an *example* of how it can be done

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid bit-shifting by assigning into a variant record which I think makes the code below more efficient.

```
function GetSizeOfFile(const Filename: string): Int64;
type
  TSizeType = (stDWORD, stInt64);
var
 sizerec: packed record
   case TSizeType of
     stDWORD: (SizeLow: LongWord; SizeHigh: LongWord);
     stInt64: (Size: Int64);
 end;
 sr : TSearchRec;
begin
  if FindFirst(fileName, faAnyFile, sr ) <> 0 then
  begin
    Result := -1;
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    sizerec.SizeLow := sr.FindData.nFileSizeLow;
    sizerec.SizeHigh := sr.FindData.nFileSizeHigh;
    Result := sizerec.Size;
  finally
    SysUtils.FindClose(sr) ;
  end;
end;
```

I could've just used "case Boolean of" but like to use the power of Pascal to make the code more descriptive.